# I want to upload multiple file to sever using flutter and php, but only one file is being uploaded

Tags: php, flutter, dart

Here is flutter code

```
var file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("file", _file[0].path);
var file2 = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("file2", _file[1].path);
var file3 = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("file3", _file[2].path);
request.files.add(file);
request.files.add(file2);
request.files.add(file3);
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();`
```

here  is php code

```
<?php
  $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $file2 = $_FILES['file2']['name'];
  $file3 = $_FILES['file3']['name'];
  $imagePath = 'upload/'.$file;
  $imagePath2 = 'upload/'.$file2;
  $imagePath3 = 'upload/'.$file3;
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
  $tmp_name2 = $_FILES['file2']['tmp_name2'];
  $tmp_name3 = $_FILES['file3']['tmp_name3'];
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$imagePath);
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_name2,$imagePath2);
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_name3,$imagePath3);
 ?>
```

I am trying to upload three files to server but only one file is uploaded

Answer (score -1):

### I hope this will work

```
Map<String, String> headers = <String, String>{
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    };

    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', file1));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file2', file2));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    http.Response rootResponse = await http.Response.fromStream(
        await request.send());
```

Comment: it seems to be uploading only a single file not all three files at once